# How can I grep for a word in a specific part of a file?

Tags: unix, sed, grep

How to grep a word in 100 to 200 lines from file using grep and sed?

Answer (score 2):

```
  grep "word" file(s)
```

for instance

```
 grep word *
```

searches for  word in all files in the current directory. To print 100 -200 line do

```
 sed -n '100,200p'
```

So combined you get

```
 sed -n '100,200p' *|grep word
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk.

```
cat "$FILE" | awk 'NR>=100 && NR<=200 && /regex/'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t mind using perl instead, the most straightforward solution is

```
$ perl -nle 'print if 100 .. 200 && /regex/'  somefile
```